# Comparing Result Set Against Itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I would like to compare against itself - so far this query is working (if there is a neater/better way to write it I'd like to know!) but it's producing some "duplicate" values.

```
SELECT 
a.GroupID,
a.MemberH,
a.ChartID as ChartIDA,
b.ChartID as ChartIDB
FROM
(Select DISTINCT
s.GroupID,
c.ChartID,
m.MemberH
From Charts c, ChartRetrieval cr, Sites s, Members m
Where 
c.ChartID=cr.ChartID
and cr.ChartScanningStatusID <> 331
and s.SiteID=c.SiteID
and s.ProjectID not in (1,2,111)
and m.MemberID=c.MemberID) a

INNER JOIN

(Select DISTINCT
s.GroupID,
c.ChartID,
m.MemberH
From Charts c, ChartRetrieval cr, Sites s, Members m
Where 
c.ChartID=cr.ChartID
and cr.ChartScanningStatusID <> 331
and s.SiteID=c.SiteID
and s.ProjectID not in (1,2,111)
and m.MemberID=c.MemberID) b ON a.GroupID=b.GroupID AND a.MemberHICN=b.MemberHICN

WHERE 
a.GroupID=b.GroupID
and a.MemberH=b.MemberH
and a.ChartID <> b.ChartID
Order By a.GroupID
```

So far the results are correct but as I said it's giving me some dupes.

IE -

```
Group ID | MemberH   | ChartIDA | ChartIDB
-----------------------------------------
471021   | 810392941 | 4810391  | 2193845
-----------------------------------------
471021   | 810392941 | 2193845  | 4810391
```

I know these rows are technically not duplicates but the info is the same just flipped (so for me they are dupes lol).

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: On top of the CTE, change your A.ChartID <> B.ChartID to something like A.ChartID > B.ChartID.  This will limit the matches to one direction instead of having A.ChartID > B.ChartID and A.ChartID < B.ChartID in the same result set.

Comment: @jtimperley This is not a CTE but it would be a good fit here.

Comment: @rageit I initially typed it against the previous result which was deleted.  You could use a CTE to consolidate your copy-paste query.

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to understand the logic of how this would work? Since I need to find it where the MemberH of both tables are the same, GroupID is the same, but the ChartIDs are NOT - so I'm not sure how having a.ChartID < b.ChartID would work for me?

Comment: BTW what is a CTE >.>

Comment: You'll still match on MemberH, you will just only get half of the pairs.  Since you've already declared that ChartID cannot match, given A, B must be either greater or equal but cannot be both.  Your problem ultimate ends up being that SQL Server will include all combinations which will find both pairs. (CTE = Common Table Expression, looks something like USING MyCTE (Column1, Column2) WITH (SELECT * FROM table join table2...) SELECT * FROM MyCTE JOIN MyCTE...

Comment: For CTEs is there an article/link you can direct me to so I can learn more about them?

Comment: You could have googled it. You can start off [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Something doesn't quite make sense to me.  Are there always going to be at most two rows for each group id/member id combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick :

```
and a.ChartID <> b.ChartID
```

Instead of

```
and a.ChartID < b.ChartID
```

This will show only one of the two rows.

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to understand the logic of how this would work?  Since I need to find it where the MemberH of both tables are the same, GroupID is the same, but the ChartIDs are not - so I'm not sure how having a.ChartID < b.ChartID would work for me?

Comment: With your query you get always two rows for each match. You keep just the one where the first chart id is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

This is half an answer as it does not cover the duplicate rows. You could self join a CTE in order to have a smaller query:

```
;WITH SomeQuery AS (
    SELECT 
    a.GroupID,
    a.MemberH,
    a.ChartID as ChartIDA,
    b.ChartID as ChartIDB
    FROM
    (Select DISTINCT
    s.GroupID,
    c.ChartID,
    m.MemberH
    From Charts c, ChartRetrieval cr, Sites s, Members m
    Where 
    c.ChartID=cr.ChartID
    and cr.ChartScanningStatusID <> 331
    and s.SiteID=c.SiteID
    and s.ProjectID not in (1,2,111)
    and m.MemberID=c.MemberID)   
)

SELECT A.* 
FROM SomeQuery A
INNER JOIN SomeQuery B
ON A.GroupID = B.GroupID AND A.MemberHICN = B.MemberHICN
WHERE 
A.GroupID = B.GroupID
and A.MemberH = B.MemberH
and A.ChartID <> B.ChartID
Order By A.GroupID
```

More about [Common Table Expressions here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: I see a lot of mentions of CTEs but I have no idea what they are! lol - is there a link/article you can direct me to to get a better idea of what they are?

Comment: CTEs aren't always the best way to go. When used in a stored procedure, you may see intermittent performance issues caused by a CTE.

Comment: Thanks for the info and this works! I just needed to incorporate the answer from above as well since keeping the "and A.ChartID <> B.ChartID" still produces the dupes.